# Pdf of $X+Y+Z$ where $X,Y,Z$ are independent $U(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

[image: Work]

[image]
[image]

This is my working out of the problem so far, I want to know if there is a more simpler way to solve this, or I would just be interested in other methods that one could use to solve a similar problem

Comment: Note that in order to use convolutions, the random variables must be independent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631501/finding-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-three-independent-uniform-random-variable

Comment: Hi, please consider using LaTeX or MathJax next time .. thanks

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin-Hall_distribution#Special_cases

Comment: Prom what I can read of your handwriting, it seems you are mainly on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.
The characteristic function of $W$ is
\begin{multline*}
\varphi_{W}(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itW}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it(X+Y+Z)}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itY}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itZ}\right]\\
=\left(\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right]\right)^{3}=\left(\varphi_{X}(t)\right)^{3}=\left(\frac{i-i\cos t+\sin t}{t}\right)^{3}.
\end{multline*}
To go from the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) to the probability density, [take its Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae):
\begin{multline*}
f_{W}(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-itw}\varphi_{W}(t)dt
=\frac{1}{4}(w^{2}\operatorname{sgn}(w)+\left(w-3\right)^{2}\operatorname{sgn}(3-w)\\+3\left(w-1\right)^{2}\operatorname{sgn}(1-w)-3\left(w-2\right)^{2}\operatorname{sgn}(2-w)).
\end{multline*}
The advantage of this method is that in many cases, you end up with functions whose Fourier transforms are easily available in print or through [symbolic computing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22((i-i*cos(t)%2Bsin(t))%2Ft)%5E3%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22,%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22w%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22fourier%20transform%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22,%20%22dflt%22%7D).

The density looks as one would expect: supported on $(0,3)$ and with a maximum at $1.5$:

[image: Probability density of W]

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) shown in Wikipedia. (See 'special case' $n = 3.)$ The PDF for the sum of three *independent* standard uniform random
variables is a 'spline' of three parabolic parts, which looks roughly normal with mean 1.5 and variance 1/4.

Simulating this distribution in R with a million instances of adding three
standard uniform random variables, one obtains the distribution shown in the
histogram below.

```
set.seed(1019)     #for reproducibility
s = replicate(10^6, sum(runif(3)))
hist(s, br=30, prob=T, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.8))
  curve(.5*x^2, 0, 1, add=T)
    curve(.5*(-2*x^2 + 6*x - 3), 1, 2, add=T)
       curve(.5*(x^2 - 6*x + 9), 2, 3, add=T)
  curve(dnorm(x, 1.5, 1/2), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
```

[image]

The exact density function on $(0,3)$ of the sum is shown as a black curve. The density function of the (roughly) approximating normal distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=3/2, \sigma=1/2)$ is shown as a dotted red curve.

*Note:* If you add 12 independent standard normal random variables, it is difficult to see a distinction between the actual distribution and the density of $\mathsf{Norm}(6, 1).$ Because the uniform distribution is symmetrical,
the limit in the Central Limit Theorem is approximately achieved for rather small $n.$