# How to determine the values of $w$ when calculating the PDF of $W = X+Y+Z$?

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the problems about finding $X+Y+Z$ where $X, Y, Z$ are uniformly distributed random variables, each in the interval of $[0,1]$. (please reference: [Finding the distribution of the sum of three independent uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631501/finding-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-three-independent-uniform-random-variable))

I understand most of the derivations, but the only part I do not understand is from the point where  $0 \leq s \leq 1,$ and $w-1 \leq s 
\leq w$.

The solutions that I have seen jump directly to divide $w$ into three different situations:

1. $w < 0$ and $w >3$
2. $1<w < 2$
3. $2 < w < 3$

Would anyone please show me how I can know the ranges of values to consider by looking at the two inequalities?
$$(0 \leq s \leq 1,\text{ and }w-1 \leq s \leq w)$$

To clarify my confusion, I started with *s* = 0, and I will get 0 < = *w* <= 1.

Then, I let *s* = 1, and I get 1 < = *w* <= 2.

Comparing with the solution, the interval of [0,1] is not considered. Also, I have no way of getting the interval of (-infinity, 0) and (3, infinity) since I have no way of knowing 3 is a value that I should consider.

What have I missed in my analysis?

Comment: you already knows that the density of $X+Y+Z$, assuming they are independent of each other, is generated by convolution of it individual densities?

Comment: What is $v$?  And you seem to be missing $0 \lt w \lt 1$

Comment: My apology. My textbook uses V while the forum uses S. I have already update my question above.

Comment: They have used the change of variable method in integration. See the argument of function has changed from $w-u$ to $u$. Hence limits are updated accordingly.