# How to solve integral with variable limits?

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals

In one of the questions that I'm solving, I have got an integral like this
$$k(w) = \int_{w-1}^{w}f(x)dx$$
where the function $f(x)$ is defined in this way
$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x,& \text{if }  0\leq x \leq 1\\
    2-x,& \text{if }  1\leq x \leq 2\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The support of $w$ is $[0,3]$. I know that the final solution will be a piecewise function like this
$$k(w)= 
\begin{cases}
    g_1(w),& \text{if }  0\leq w \leq 1\\
    g_2(w),& \text{if }  1\leq w \leq 2\\
    g_3(w),& \text{if }  2\leq w \leq 3\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$.

Give me some idea about solving this type of integrals.

**Note**: This integral is an intermediate step in the proof of three variables Irwine Hall distribution. Check the first answer for this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631501/finding-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-three-independent-uniform-random-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $0<w\le 1$

$k(w) = \int_{w-1}^w f(x) \ dx = \int_{w-1}^0 f(x) \ dx + \int_{0}^w f(x) \ dx\\
k(w) = \int_{w-1}^0 0 \ dx + \int_{0}^w x \ dx = \frac 12 w^2$

Case 1: $1<w\le 2$

$k(w) = \int_{w-1}^1 x \ dx + \int_{1}^w 2-x \ dx\\
\frac 12 - \frac 12 (w-1)^2 - \frac 12 (2-w)^2 + \frac 12 = - w^2 + 3w - \frac 32$

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to write $f(x)$ as a sum of $f_i(x) \theta(x-x_i)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step-function, and integrate each term. Once you have the anti-derivative $F(x)$ as a sum of step-functions, you can express $F(w)-F(w-1)$ generally