# Cumulative distribution function of weighted sum of random uniform variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

> I'm not very familiar with the mathematical jargon of probabilities, so I apologize in advance for any mistakes I might make.

### Short version

I want to know how to compute the cumulative distribution of the weighted sum of $n$ uniform variables. Specifically, the sum $S$ is computed as

$$
S = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{n}\ R_i\ \times\ P^{n - 1}
$$

Where $R_i$ is a uniform random variable in the range $[-1, 1]$ and $P$ a constant real number (normally, $0 < P < 1$).

### Long version

> Perlin noise is a type of gradient noise developed by Ken Perlin in 1983. It has many uses, including but not limited to: procedurally generating terrain, applying pseudo-random changes to a variable, and assisting in the creation of image textures.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)

When generating Perlin noise, it is common to overlap many octaves (each in the range$[-1, 1]$ to create more detailed looking noise. These octaves are assigned different weights. The parameter used to control this is called `persistance`. The weight of the $n$th octave is $persistance^{n - 1}$. Finally, this sum is normalized to bring the value back to a $[-1, 1]$ range.

One of the nice characteristics of Perlin noise is that it has a uniform distribution: each value in the range $[-1, 1]$ is equally likely. However, using many octaves ruins this, since the distribution becomes a normal distribution. Hence, I would like to tranform it into a uniform distribution using probability integral transform.

For this, the cumulative distribution function is needed. I've looked into [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution) and [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), but they assume an equal weight for each of the variables being added.

**Here is the question:**

I want to know how to compute the cumulative distribution of the weighted sum of $n$ uniform variables. Specifically, the sum $S$ is computed as

$$
S = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{n}\ R_i\ \times\ P^{n - 1}
$$

Where $R_i$ is a uniform random variable in the range $[-1, 1]$ and $P$ a constant real number (normally, $0 < P < 1$).

**Final notes**

I've lost all hope of implementing this in code, but I'm curious to know the formula anyway. Just for the sake of curiosity, my plan is to sample something like a million values, arrange them in a thousand "buckets" and compute the cumulative probability function with them.

- More details on Perlin noise and its uses can be found on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbpMiKiSKm8&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3&index=1) video by Sebastian Lague (one of my favorite youtubers, btw).
- For a different explanation of the problem with uniform Perlin noise, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549851/uniform-distribution-from-a-fractal-perlin-noise-function-in-c-sharp) question on StackOverflow (just ignore the paragraph about Matlab).

Comment: The characteristic function (note: this characterizes a probability distribution) has semi-closed form if we are supposing these $(R_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent:
$$E[e^{i\xi S}]=\prod_{1\leq k\leq n}E[e^{i\xi p^{k-1}R_k}]=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{e^{i\xi p^{k-1}}-e^{-i\xi p^{k-1}}}{2i\xi p^{k-1}}=\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\frac{\sin(\xi p^{k-1})}{\xi p^{k-1}}$$
for $\xi \neq 0$ and $=1$ for $\xi =0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of the  distribution you seek is a spline polynomial of degree $n-1$ that has $2^n$ nodes. However,your  distribution actually  stabilizes quickly with just a few values of $n$.
Here is picture of an example of the distribution, with $p=1/3$ and $n=5$ convolutional layers. You get essentially the same picture with just $n=3$ layers. The reason? When you adjoin more layers of complexity  you are convolving the prior probability distributions  with rectangular window functions that have very narrow widths and are essentially delta functions.

**Note.** Modifying the observation in Snoop's comment, I used the convention $R=[0,1]$ rather than $ R=[-1,1]$ ( so that I could use a built-in Laplace transform inverter rather than the Fourier transform). This translation of the center of the interval merely has the effect of re-centering the distribution you seek.

See this related post for additional info regarding sums of uniformly distributed random variables that live on different intervals.
[sums of uniform random variables with different support intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634166/finding-the-cdf-of-a-sum-of-n-independent-uniform-random-variables-with-differen/4634336#4634336)

[image]

Comment: Hi there! It'll take me some time to digest your answer, since this is not a domain of mathematics I'm very familiar with... Anyway, thanks for the effort you put into it!